# How to make RGB image more magenta (in Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am writing a code that could make an  overall view of RGB image more magenta. Can anyone show some elegant way to do this in Matlab? 
How can I make an RGB image more magenta (Matlab code)?

Comment: `img(:,:,1) = img(:,:,3) = 255;` Quantify "more magenta". Please provide a [mcve] including sample input and output images as well as your code. You should also add the [tag:matlab] tag.

Comment: If you mean the magenta in CMYK color then you can first convert the RGB image to CMYK image, and adjust the M channel as your wish, and finally convert it back to RGB.